# USB Storage Problem

Tags: storage, lenovo-a660

I bought a new smartphone and everything was fine when I connected with my computer. I don't
know what exactly I did but after I unplug it an app called 'System UI' was spamming my screen to turn off USB Storage but the button was inactive. I didn't know what to do and I forced stopped the app. Now some features are temporarily inactive from this charging all my photos are missing, my apps that I had installed now are uninstalled. Please tell me HOW TO FIX IT ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you already try rebooting the phone to force a remount of the storage devices? If not remounted you should be able to mount it manually from Settings > Storage.

Comment: How to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Certainly reboot. It sounds like you might have unplugged it while the computer was still accessing the usb storage. Make sure to use the safe removal feature and try again.

Comment: Didn't work :C.